# Finding the sum of a series..

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How does one determine the sum of this series?

$$ \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{(x+2)^n}{(n+3)!} $$

I was given a hint that there's something in this that should look familiar to another series, but I am unfortunately drawing a blank.

Comment: If you shift the indices so that the denominator becomes $n!$, do you then see something?

Comment: it looks so much like the exponential function...

Comment: My apologies, it's late & I had to refresh myself on that concept. I see how this is useful, but I'm not 100% sure how to proceed... I assume this would turn the series into (x+2)^n / (n!), correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
 $$e^{x+2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(x+2)^{n}}{n!}=1+(x+2)+\frac{(x+2)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(x+2)^{3}}{3!}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(x+2)^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}.$$ Therefore

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(x+2)^{n}}{(n+3)!}=\frac{1}{(x+2)^{3}}\left(e^{x+2}-1-(x+2)-\frac{(x+2)^{2}}{2!}-\frac{(x+2)^{3}}{3!}\right).$$

Comment: This simplifies to $$\frac{6 e^{x+2}-(x^3+9 x^2+30 x+38)}{6 (x+2)^3}$$